# Module not found Serverless Lambda Error with webpack

Tags: node.js, webpack, aws-lambda, aws-serverless

I am working with AWS lambda functions. I have configured Webpack and babel for es6 or later js versions. Everything working well. I also implemented lambda layers for common nodejs modules.
This is **serverless.yml**

```
layers:
  commonLayer:
    path: layers/common
    description: nodejs common modules
```

Here is lambda function **second** where **commonLayer** is being used

```
  second:
    handler: handlers/second.hello
    layers:
      - { Ref: CommonLayerLambdaLayer }
    events:
      - http:
          method: get
          path: second
```

I have written a function inside **commonLayer** to consume in **second** function but when I try to run **sls deploy** it gives this error

```
ERROR in ./handlers/first.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '/opt/nodejs/palindrome' in '/Users/adamanjum/Documents/workspace/serverless/handlers'
 @ ./handlers/first.js 2:0-48 11:12-22
```

[Project Repository](https://github.com/adam-qbatch/serverless)

Answer (score -1):

Your import path for `palindrome` is incorrect. In `handlers/first.js`, try changing `import palindrome from '/opt/nodejs/palindrome';` to `import palindrome from ../layers/common/nodejs/palindrome;`.

Comment: Well... it looks good and runs without any error at local but it does not fulfill aws lambda's layer concept and it gives the error after deployment.

Comment: This solves the error you posted, which was specifically in a scenario involving `sls offline`. You may wish to update your original post.

Comment: Adam, did you ever get the deploy aspect of this sorted out? I am facing the exact same issue with using serverless-bundle